# Windows service stops if there was an exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, timer

I developed Windows service that is using System.Threading.Timer. Timer is starting every x minutes and it works fine (timer is updatet at the end of method). But, if there is an error in try block service just stops despite the fact that I'm updating timer and telling him when to start again 
why is that happening? Here is code :

```
 System.Threading.Timer serviceTimer;

 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
 {
     TimeSpan diff;
     diff = nextRun - now;
     TimerCallback timerDelegate =
         new TimerCallback(MyTimerCallback);
     serviceTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, 
         diff, new TimeSpan(-1));
 }

 public  void MyTimerCallback(object something)
 {   
    try
    {
        //possible error that happened
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        //diff is a new variable telling timer when to start again 
        serviceTimer.Change(diff, new TimeSpan(-1));
    }
 }
```

what am I missing why service stops if there was an error?

Comment: What are you doing in the `catch` block?

Comment: in try block I'm calling a method on web service:
 var result = proxy.ProxyMethod(param,param);
so there is possible error if service is not available

Comment: If there is such an error, your service _will_ stop with an unhandled exception.

Comment: any how there is some lines that could couse an error. Thing is that timer is not working if there is an error. For instance I made error on purpose inside try block

Comment: string value = null;
                if (value.Length == 0) <-- Causes exception
                {
                   Console.WriteLine(value);  <-- Never reached
                //}
If this code is in try block timer 'll not start again

Comment: Correct. The application will exit because you didn't handle the exception that occurred in the `catch` block. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: Why is that possible, I tought that finally block 'll always be reached no matter what?

Comment: The `finally` block will indeed execute - but if there's an unhandled exception heading out of the `catch` block, that's going to trigger the unhandled exception handler, which is going to exit the process.

Comment: O i get it so what is the best way to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the timer wasn't able to change. [`Timer.Change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz1c7148.aspx) returns a boolean:

> **true** if the timer was successfully updated; otherwise, **false**.

But you're not checking that result. I'd recommend probably disposing the timer and `new`ing up a new one each time, since it's already fired and you created it as a "one shot" timer, e.g.

```
finally
{
    serviceTimer.Dispose();
    serviceTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, null, 
     diff, new TimeSpan(-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that someone deals with same problem I figured something like this:

Since I want my service to stay alive no matter what :
I 'm  reporting to the service manager that the service has successfully started -

```
 base.OnStart(args);
```

In configuration you can set legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy set to true (1)